Can standalone components handle nested ngModules?
How to correctly handle below scenario ?
StandaloneComponent ( needs for example ReactiveFormsModule )
ModuleA
ModuleB ( imports ReactiveFormsModule)
If I got above structure reactive forms module is not recognized in standalone… how it should looks like ?

In the standalone component also import ReactiveFormsModule: imports:[ReactiveFormsModule,ModuleA,ModuleB]

Standalone component require explicit imports.
If you component want to use a directive from ReactiveFormsModule you'll need to import it. There is no transitive import in the case standalone.
